# Write windows specific .pri file for Qt application

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to build a Qt 5.5 application on Windows 8.1. I manged to build the same application on both Ubuntu 14.04 and MacOS 10.10.2.

This is how the .pri file looks like right now: http://pastebin.com/USHBXAni.
It has both unix and mac support. I tried to add windows support too, but it is not working. It looks like this:

```
win32 {

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD \
   C:/Program Files (x86)/PCL 1.7.2/3rdParty/Boost/include/boost-1_57 \
   C:/opencv/build/include

LIBS += -L/C:/opencv/build/x86/vc12/lib \
   -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml \
   -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt

LIBS += -L/C:/Program Files (x86)/PCL 1.7.2/3rdParty/Boost/lib \
   -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt

}
```

I am really new to this and I am sure it is syntactically incorrect, but should be something similar to this. Anybody could give me some hints or help would be much appreciated!

What is $$PWD and -L for example?

The error after running make:

> cd tests\test_galif\ && ( if not exist Makefile
>   C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013\bin\q make.exe
>   C:\Users\Concordia\Documents\OpenSSE\opensse-master\tests\test_galif\te
>   st_galif.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile make[1]: Entering
>   directory `C:/Users/Concordia/Documents/OpenSSE/opensse-master
>   /tests/test_galif' make -f Makefile.Release make[2]: Entering
>   directory`C:/Users/Concordia/Documents/OpenSSE/opensse-master
>   /tests/test_galif' Makefile.Release:106: *** missing separator.  Stop.
>   make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `C:/Users/Concordia/Documents/OpenSSE/opensse-master/
>   tests/test_galif' make[1]: *** [release] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving
>   directory`C:/Users/Concordia/Documents/OpenSSE/opensse-master/
>   tests/test_galif' make: *** [sub-tests-test_galif-make_first] Error 2

Comment: What is your error? What is Qt version? `$$PWD` points to the project directory. `-L` is used for linker library path (without slash `-LC:/...` or and also quoted `-L"C:/..."`).

Comment: You're linking with opencv compiled with vc12 (visual studio 2013). Is also Qt built with vc12?

Comment: Hi, I added Qt version (5.+) and the error output after running make.

Comment: Qt is installed via the installer (open-source version) provided on their website. But the include and bin folders are under msvc2013 folder.

Comment: Where did you get `make`? It is not supposed to be here. How do you build your project? If it is built from console it should be built from MSVC console and `nmake` should be used instead `make`.

Comment: I opened a cmd window, then run the qmake command and after qmake finished I ran the make command. So I guess this is totally wrong then? I will look into MSVC console, but I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cmd` Windows console the tool `make` should not be found:

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

If `make` is found it comes from some foreign installation (maybe from Cygwin). `qmake` from `msvc2013` Qt installation by default should generate Makefiles for Visual Studio `nmake`.

The build from console should be started from appropriate command prompt that has proper build environment (`%PATH%` variable). For 32 bit compilation it should be `x86` command prompt:

```
Programs->Visual Studio 2013->Visual Studio Tools->VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt
```

From that console it should be possible to run `nmake` and appropriate compiler.

It should help with the Makefile error. It is possible that there are some other compiler or linker errors, but they will be revealed only with correct build environment by suitable make tool.

---

In general if some error is reported due to Makefile format on some line (for example `Makefile.Release:106`) it may be needed to check why there is something wrong in that line.

---

The headers path with spaces must be quoted for proper compilation:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/PCL 1.7.2/3rdParty/Boost/include/boost-1_57"
```

---

The libraries paths for the linker can be set by `-L` followed by path. The path with spaces must be quoted for proper linkage:

```
LIBS += -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/PCL 1.7.2/3rdParty/Boost/lib"
```

For completeness note that it possible to have other troubles with paths with spaces using older Qt versions [QMAKE adding extra quotations in lib path of make file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422028/qmake-adding-extra-quotations-in-lib-path-of-make-file)
However, Qt5.5.1 is not affected by that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will try it as soon as I can!

Comment: With your explanation and some research on MSVC+nmake and Qt I was finnaly able to build the application!